# how to relate SPARQL queries records of 1-many relationships or how to move partial duplicates?

Tags: duplicates, sparql, dbpedia

I'm making a query on dbpedia which returns the religion information of a country.

However, the situation is that a religion of the country could be retrieved with dbo:Religion while I need another information, which is the percentage of this religion in this country.  This could only be retrieved by another term dbp:Religion.

The problem is there is no connection between these two terms dbo:Religion and dbp:Religion, so the final result returned is as follows:

| Country | Religion | ReligionPercentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | Demographics | 99.7% |
| Afghanistan | Demographics | 0.3% |
| Afghanistan | Islam | 0.3% |
| Afghanistan | Islam | 99.7% |

while my expected result should be

| Country | Religion | ReligionPercentage |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| Afghanistan  | Demographics    | 99.7% |
| Afghanistan  | Islam    | 0.3% |
Follows my query

```
SELECT str(?Country)AS ?Country str(?Religion) AS ?Religion ?religionPercentage WHERE { 
?s dbo:religion ?o .
FILTER(EXISTS {
?s a dbo:Country;
dbo:capital ?capital;
dbo:area ?area;
dbo:countryCode ?CountryCode;
dbo:populationTotal ?Population})
?s dbp:religion ?religionPercentage.
FILTER(datatype(?religionPercentage) in (xsd:double,xsd:integer) )
?s rdfs:label ?Country.
?o rdfs:label ?Religion.
FILTER(lang(?Country) = 'en')
FILTER(lang(?Religion) = 'en')
}
GROUP BY ?Country ?Religion ?religionPercentage
ORDER BY ASC(?Country)
```

Is there any solution on this one to many relationships?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the data. First of all, "demographics" is clearly **not** a religion, right? I mean, check the corresponding page [demographics of Afganisthan](https://dbpedia.org/page/Demographics_of_Afghanistan) - it's obviously about the distribution of different facets of the population (age, male/female) in the country

Comment: Then, it is impossible to combine the religion with the percentage because, how? there is no order in RDF triples, all you have is `country dbo:eligion :religion1, :religion2, ...., religion_n`  and `country dbp:religion :religionPercentage1, :religionPercentage2, ..., :religionPercentage_n` - but nobody know which percentage belongs to which religion.

Comment: This needs an n_ary relation which in RDF is only possible via additional intermediate nodes. For example, `:Afghanistan :religion :afghanistan_religion1. :afghanistan_religion1 :religionType :Islam . :afghanistan_religion1 :religionPercentage 15.0 .` - but that's not how DBpedia modeled it so the data is useless and the quality is bad anyways

Comment: By the way, did you really think the percentage of Islam in Afghanistan should be 0.3%? The Wikipedia page shows 99,7% Islam, 0.3% Others. So the extraction from the infobox is just wrong.

Comment: Also, I'm wondering why you used `GROUP BY` in your query? I mean, the whole purpose of grouping is to apply some aggregate function, otherwise it's unnecessary

Comment: Thanks for the comment from 'UninformedUser'. Now I know the fact that the data is wrong. Is there any other solution to find the percentage of corresponding religions in a country? Only by using data and terms from dbpedia.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so. It's just the problem that the data isn't there or at least not in a usable form (nor in a good quality). Using Wikidata as an alternative is also not possible given that the data doesn't exists there at all, see https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Request_a_query/Archive/2020/11#List_of_religions_by_country

Comment: Anyway, thank you and it's all right. I was also wondering whether this question has an eligible solution for several days and for this I've also been searching for many materials or related posts in stackoverflow. This is almost the very approaching answer I could make query of.